On the gain of an NPN Common-Emitter Amplifier without emitter degeneration
I tried to get the voltage gain (\$ A_v \$) of a Grounded Common-Emitter (GCE) Amplifier (see Fig. 1), which in many electronic textbooks is provided (sometimes without showing some algebra) and is defined as: \$ A_v = -g_mR_c\$.
It must be highlighted that this question was so far answered previously and that jonk's response shed quite a bit of light on this topic: How to derive the precise gain of an NPN common emitter amplifier without emitter degeneration? However, I would like to review it. The main reason is because I would like to understand deeply the physical-mathematical model of this circuit that a priori seems "simple". To do that, I believe that the best way is to show the math to obtain a model of this circuit configuration.

Fig. 1. Schematic of a GCE Amplifier
It is well-known that in GCE configuration, the BJT is in active mode. Therefore, we can say:
\$ I_c=I_s \cdot (e^\frac{V_{in}}{V_T}-1) \$, where \$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage.
Assuming an appropiate DC-bias point plus small-signal input voltage, we can say:
\$ V_{in}=V_{in,q}+\delta V_{in} \$
And, after some algebra, we obtain:
\$ I_c=I_s \cdot (e^\frac{V_{in,q}}{V_T}e^\frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T}-1)=I_{c,q}+\delta I_c\$
Defining \$ I_{c,q}\$ as: \$ I_{c,q}=I_se^\frac{V_{in,q}}{V_T} \$, we obtain \$ \delta I_c\$:
\$ \delta I_c=I_{c,q}(e^\frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T}-1)-Is \$
We know that the output voltage: \$ V_0=V_{0,q}+\delta V_0 \$ and so that: \$ \delta V_0 =-R_c \delta I_c\$
So, by sustitution:
\$ \delta V_0 =-R_c (I_{c,q}(e^\frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T}-1)-Is)\$
Why do I think this analytical expression is correct? Well, if we assume that \$ \delta V_{in} << V_T \$, we can expand the exponential to the first term of Taylor's Series:
\$ e^\frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T} \approx 1 + \frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T} \$
Therefore: \$ \delta I_c = I_{c,q}\frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T}-Is\$
Neglecting \$ I_s \$ with regard to \$I_{c,q}\frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T}\$ we obtain:
\$ \delta I_c = I_{c,q}\frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T} \$ and hence, the output voltage is: \$ \delta V_0 =-R_cI_{c,q}\frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T}\$.
Remember that \$ I_{c,q}=I_se^\frac{V_{in,q}}{V_T} \$.
And, finally: \$ \delta V_0 =-R_cI_se^\frac{V_{in,q}}{V_T} \frac{\delta V_{in}}{V_T}=-g_mR_c \delta V_{in}\$ that allow us to say: \$ A_v = -g_mR_c\$.
To me, this is the process to obtain properly \$ A_v \$ and at this point, I would like to formulate my questions:

It was shown that the famous parameter \$ \beta \$ does not appear in \$ A_v \$, or almost does not appear directly. But this is true if we use the Ebers-Moll equation for the collector current \$ I_c=I_s \cdot (e^\frac{V_{in}}{V_T}-1) \$ as done at the beginning of the process. However, one can define the base current of the BJT as \$ I_b=I_s \cdot (e^\frac{V_{in}}{V_T}-1) \$ and use \$ \beta \$ to obtain \$ I_c \$ afterwards. This would lead that \$ A_v =-\beta g_mR_c\$ by following the same process (not shown for the sake of clarity). Which one is correct? Am I missing something? The collector current equation shown here can be used only for a BJT in active mode? The \$ \beta \$ approach can be used also in active mode, where is the difference?
There is a thing that makes me suspect that the expression for \$ A_v \$ obtained it is not entirely correct, or perhaps I am not interpreting it well. The equation obtained means to me that \$ A_v \$ is just a number since \$ R_c \$ is a number (5 k\$\Omega\$ for example) and \$ g_m \$ is evaluated at the operating point. But I think that \$ A_v\$ should varies, right? I mean, if I perform a simulation in LTSpice and computes \$ \delta V_o / \delta V_{in} \$ I would see how \$ A_v\$ varies. But in the formula I don't see that phenomena. Any help in this? What am I missing here? As an example, suppose you applied an appropiate \$ V_{be} =636 [mV] \$ to the base of the BJT plus a triangular waveform of 60 [mVpp] @1kHz. The bias point is 636 [mV], so I don't see why the voltage-gain change with the operating point. I would expect that the gain varies with the base-voltage swings.


Are you using the same I_s for the base and collector currents?

A_v varies with the operating point and temperature.

Thanks John Doty for your point. To clarify my second question I added an example there. Regarding the $I_s$, I wrote that question theoretically. Sure would not be the same and depends where is defined the saturation current and maybe $ \beta $ play its role there?

In the model,
is the ratio of the different
for the collector and base.

Ok, so considering your answer we would say that $ \beta $ is therefore included in the saturation collector current, named $I_s$, as follows: $ I_c=\beta I_{s,b}(e^{\frac{V_{in}}{V_T}}-1) $, where  $  I_{s,b}$ is the saturation-base current, doesn't it? If yes, therefore $ \beta $ appears in the voltage-gain equation but has little influence since is multiplied by $  I_{s,b}$. Moreover, the equation I wrote that shows dependence of $  A_v$ with $ \beta $ is totally wrong.

Substitute $I_{s,b}\rightarrow I_{s,c}/\beta$ and recover $I_c= I_{s,c}(e^{\frac{V_{in}}{V_T}}-1)$. $\beta$ cancels.

Ok. I think you want to say something like this: $ \frac{I_c}{\beta}=\frac{I_{s,c}}{\beta}(e^\frac{V_{in}}{V_T}-1)  $

The relevant operating point is whatever the instantaneous condition is at a point in time. So, yes, you'll have different gains at 636 mV and 666 mV. The output signal will not be triangular for a triangular input.

So, to clarify. The process I did to obtain the gain is correct? Can we say that? and all I have to do is to "see" the DC + triangular waveform as a variation of the bias point right?

Are we just getting hung up on asking why your answer isn't exact when you took an approximation by using only the linear terms of the Taylor series expansion?

Dear Ste Kulov, this is not the main focus of the question. I'm not trying to obtain an exact analytical expression. Just want to explore the limits of the mathematical models, and some misunderstanding with regard to the models used. Please, read carefully the text I wrote.

@cardompal  I know.  I was just trying to address the triangle wave thing.  Anyway, regarding everything else, these scans from Semiconductor Device Modeling with SPICE might be of interest to you:  https://i.sstatic.net/nSdbpaMP.png  https://i.sstatic.net/rE7Tibhk.png

The linear approximation is only accurate for $\Delta V << V_T$.

Thanks @JohnDoty but I think this is what I wrote, right? That $ \delta V_{in} << V_T $.

@cardompal Yes, so why do you expect it works for $\delta V$ of 30 mV, a bit larger than $V_T$ at room temperature?

@cardompal With regard to the question in your first bullet, I'd suggest the first level (DC only) large scale Ebers-Moll models shown in this answer from jonk at EESE. (The hybrid-$\pi$ version, an equivalent model that was developed much later on, is the one more often used these days.) There's no source for confusion that I see. So yes, I think you are missing something in your work product.

@John Doty I understand your question. One thing is how works the CGE amplifier and how to achieve that simple expression for $A_v$, that is: $ \delta V_{in} << V_T $. That is for sure. If noy, you have tu use the complex expression for $ \delta V_0$ which is exponential. I know that with $ \delta V_{in}$= 300 [$\mu$Vpp] for example there will be no distortion at the output. But that is another topic.   So, that is not the aim of my example. The aim is just to understand $ \beta $ dependence, and probably I failed describing it in my question. Hope now is more understandable.

@cardompal In the model you're using, with $V_in$ as the independent variable, there is no $\beta$ dependence of the transconductance.

@cardompal Let's see the not shown for the sake of clarity work product. The problem lays in your first bullet lays there. You should be aware that the non-linear hybrid-$\pi$ model is aphysical in that it combines two PN junction current generators into a single source. This moves away from a physical understanding, without loss of generality. But it does move away, leaving physical insights about PN junctions behind in exchange for simplicity in relating the non-linear large scale model to the linearized small (infinitesimal) scale model. Injection model is better for intuition.

Quote: "**It was shown that the famous parameter β does not appear in Av, or almost does not appear directly. But this is true if we use the Ebers-Moll equation for the collector current....."*
Yes - this is correct. But not only because it is based on a certain model. Just the other way round: This model does reflect real physical facts (in contrast to some other simple models which are based on Ic=B*Ib). For a fixed DC-operating point, the so-called "current gain" has no influence on voltage gain Av. It has an influence on the signal input resistance only.
Quote: However, one can define the base current of the BJT..... and use β to obtain Ic afterwards. This would lead that Av=−βgmRc by following the same process (not shown for the sake of clarity). Which one is correct?"*
No - there must be an error in your calculation. Starting with the base current, the small-signal base-emitter resistance rbe=hie should appear in your calculation and the result would be: Av=-(β/hie)Rc which is correct because gm=β/hie.
This is because ube=ib*hie.

Ic=B*Ib represents a real physical fact, as you may easily verify on the bench. It's approximate, but so is every model. It's perhaps less useful as a design starting point than the exponential model, but that doesn't make it unphysical.

Thanks for your answer! So, from your answer I see that you agree with my calculations.  We'll maybe the mess is because I found this notes from an university: https://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/STONEKIM/COURSES/BJT_CE_amp_notes.pdf (hope everyone can see it). And I don't see where is the difference and why $ \beta $ appears in the voltage-gain.

@ John Doty - OK, I must admit that I have expressed myself not clear enough. Yes - it is true that the equation Ic=B*Ib represents a real physical fact - however, this expression must not be interpreted in the sense that Ic is caused/determined by Ib. This would be wrong.  This is and was the meaning of my contribution.

@ cardompal - In the linked pdf paper I can read Av=-(beta/r_pi)Rc  which is identical to Av=-gmRc.

If I connect a current source to the base, I can control the collector current. That's a physical fact. How you interpret that fact depends on which model you use: current amplifier, Eber-Moll, Gummel-Poon...

@LvW so it means that it depends if you use $ r_{\pi} $ or $ r^{'}_{e} $. But what we can conclude is that $ \beta $ has no influence at all.

@ John Doty - I am afraid that you are in error. The working principle of a BJT is not a matter of interpretation or usage of a model. The answer is simple: There is not a single proof for current control, but in contrary: All theoertical explanations, experimental observations and design rules are a proove for voltage control. Regarding your "counter example": The current source in your example is - in fact - a voltage source connected to a voltage divider consisting of a (large) ohmic base resistor and the base-emitter junction (which produces the voltage Vbe)

@LvW Yet I can do the experiment and demonstrate current control. I can also demonstrate voltage control. Either model works. That's the nature of proof in physics: mathematical theory proves nothing outside of the imaginary worlds of mathematics. Now, of course, it may be useful in that it maps onto reality, but physics is not mathematics.

It's like Ohm's law. Does the voltage across the resistor control the current, or does the current control the voltage? It isn't causal in that way: it's a relation that holds between the quantities.

@ John Doty - I cannot follow you. I think, Ohms law is not only a mathematical relation between two quantities. It rather describes the causality between voltage and current. No current without a driving voltage. Do you have a counter example?
More than that - regarding the BJT - I would be very interested to see how you can "demonstrate current control". To make it clear: I speak about the working principle of the BJT alone - not about a complete circuit which contains a BJT as an active element.

@LvW You can equally understand resistance as "no voltage without driving current". Current sensing is a common application of resistors.

@LvW You can drive the base of a transistor with a current source to control the collector current, without any knowledge or control of the base voltage.

@ John Doty - OK, I propose to end the discussion at this point. We will not come together. You are speaking of "models" and formulas and  "understanding" of resistances and that "we can drive the base....". Yes, we can do a lot of things. We even can use a VCVS as a current-to-voltage converter. But thats not my point - I refer to physical properties (voltage-current relations) of BJTs only.  I don't think that the pn junction in transistors follows completely different physical laws than the classic pn diode.

You are confusing the model (mathematics) with the physics (what happens in reality).

Thank you all for your contributions. The discussion was truly interesting. In the near future, I will answer with all your comments to be sure I understood all your points. Many thanks once again!
